# Bootstrap columns not showing correctly in Firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

My Bootstrap grid is working fine in Safari and Chrome, but not in Mozilla Firefox. It works fine when I slightly minimize it, but not on fill screen size.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
            1
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
            2
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
            3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
            a
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
            b
          </div>
          <div class="single-offer col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
            c
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Do you have any ideas why this occurs?

Comment: It's `class="container-fluid"` not `class="container fluid"`

Comment: Thanks, it makes no difference for this issue. I still have 1, 2 and 3 content row in the centre of the page, a, b and c can't fit and fall down to the next row.

Comment: What actually happens on Firefox that's different to Chrome / Safari, you've only said it displays incorrectly?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap4?

Comment: [You can't have a container inside a container](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container). And please specify what would be de desired result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that it wasn't about this part at all. The thing was that the row above had 1px of free space, so Firefox tried to jam this part into that row which messed it all up.

Solution:

```
.container-fluid>.row {clear:both}
```

Sorry everyone for misleading.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:

Had the same problem. In my case it was a stray `<br>` element in the same container as my row that turned out to be the culprit. However, before I found that out, I managed to quick-fix it in a hacky way via CSS.

Original post:

Had the same problem in my code. It looked good everywhere else but one element was pushed to the next row in Firefox.

The solution provided by the author didn't work for me so I did it in a hacky way. I set a max-width attribute to one of the columns.

I had a row made of `.col-md-3`.

Via CSS I'd set a custom max-width attribute for one of them small enough for the problem to disappear - for me it was

```
`max-width: 25%;`
```

However, right after that, I'd figured that the problem was in the stray `<br>` element that was somehow lost in the container in which my row was placed. Firefox rendered it as having a width of 0.19px while the other browsers were ignoring it. After deleting it the problem was gone.

Answer (score -1):

Your markup is incorrect. Your opening  should be:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

Comment: As mentioned above, I am aware of that, but it has nothing to do with finding the solution. It has something to do with the percentage.